# How to convert Date from JSON to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, json, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Hi I need to convert this string

> "2013-12-05T08:58:55.9345456+02:00"

to NSDate
I am trying next format but without luck

> "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSSSSSSZZZZZ"

Code below.

Can you help me with right format

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//                         "2013-12-05T08:58:55.9345456+02:00"
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSSSSSSZZZZZ"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:jsonDateString];
```

Comment: try this https://gist.github.com/exalted/726910

Comment: `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'S'+02:00'"];`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya This is not the proper format for the string.

Comment: Thank you Anoop, this works for me "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SZZZZZ"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your format is close. You need:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZZ
```

And be sure to set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`. This should always be done when parsing fixed formatted, non-localized strings.

Comment: Sorry to say, But when I tried this one, i am getting (null). I am using OSX.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Be sure to set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: Leave it, it is not working in OSX proj. This might be working on iOS project. :(

Comment: @AnoopVaidya What version of OSX?

Comment: I am using OSX- 10.7.5

Comment: @AnoopVaidya That's the problem. The `ZZZZZ` format is not supported in OSX 10.7 or earlier (or iOS 5.x or earlier). I just tested under OSX 10.8 and it works just fine.

Comment: OK... here is a lesson for me for the day :)

Comment: See the [Unicode spec for the format specifiers](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns). Version 35 (which added support for `ZZZZZ`) requires iOS 6.0 or later and OSX 10.8 and later.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * dateStr = @"2013-12-05T08:58:55.9345456+02:00";
NSArray *dateStrParts = [dateStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"T"];
NSString *datePart = [dateStrParts objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *timePart = [dateStrParts objectAtIndex:1];

NSString *t = [[timePart componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *newDateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",datePart,t];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; // Change here for your formated output
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:newDateStr];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Output

> 2013-12-05 08:58:55 +0000

Comment: Instead of all of this string processing, just use the proper date format.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the timezone where you have `+02:00`.

The `ZZZZ` only parses to `+0000`, hence you are getting `nil`.

You can do in this way:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *jsonDateString = @"2013-12-05T08:58:55.9345456+02:00";//@"2013-12-05T08:58:55.9345456+02:00"

 NSRange lastColon = [jsonDateString rangeOfString:@":" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
 if(lastColon.location != NSNotFound) {
        jsonDateString = [jsonDateString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:lastColon withString: @""];
 }

 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SZ"];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:jsonDateString];

 NSLog(@"%@",date)
```

EDIT:

As per rmaddy's comment, you should use `SSSSS` instead of single `S`.

Comment: The `+02:00` format timezone can be parsed with the `ZZZZZ` date format. And why are you throwing away the decimal seconds?

Comment: @rmaddy:its there as `S` is there...And I tried with `ZZZZZ` but its not getting parsed :(

Comment: Does a single `S` handle multiple fractional digits? Why strip the colon from the timezone? This can be handled with the proper format.